# How to convert string to array or object like in python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I'm trying to make a RabbitMQ worker in python and I'm really new to python.
I have managed to make the worker work and get data from database. From database I'm fetching a json like tuple. After converting the tuple to string with str() I'm getting this json:

```
('{"a-1":{"s":"8","m":"0:08","a":"1"},"a-2":{"s":"11","m":"0:11","a":"2"},"a-3":{"s":"11","m":"0:11","a":"2"},"a-4":{"s":"12","m":"0:12","a":"2"}}',)
```

How can I convert this string to to an array like

```
array[1] = 8;
array[2] = 11;
array[3] = 11;
```

or

```
array["a-1"] = [s=>8,m=>0:08]
```

I tried simplejson.loads and json.loads but both don't work.
The json format is wrong? If i could convert the json string to an object would be great, instead of array

Thank you

Comment: That isn't exactly JSON. It's a tuple of a string (which happens to be JSON)

Comment: Along the lines of what @cricket_007 said, `json.loads(result[0])`.

Comment: I'm getting this error with both simplejson and json json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you for your answer, after removing the str() from result and using result[0] the array now works. But why?

Comment: You are getting back a one-element tuple. The one element in that tuple is a JSON string. Using `result[0]` gets that string, and `json.loads` converts it to a dict. Note that if the API you are querying returns no results (empty tuple) the access `result[0]` will throw an `IndexError`.

Comment: something wrong with the input you provided. I have tried  aa = u'{"a-1":{"s":"8","m":"0:08","a":"1"},"a-2":{"s":"11","m":"0:11","a":"2"},"a-3":{"s":"11","m":"0:11","a":"2"},"a-4":{"s":"12","m":"0:12","a":"2"}}' Then use json.loads(aa). It works well. Please double check your input

Comment: @Mr_U4913 Yes you are right, it was my fault. I'm really new into python. Please repost the answer so I can accept it. Also do you know if there is a package manager for python to study?

Comment: Package manager? Anaconda, which contains lots of packages.